# Highlight images on page when the user clicks on them

Tags: javascript

I want to add CSS style with JavaScript: "padding", "background", and "border" to the image clicked by the user, when the user clicks again on that image, the highlight effect is removed.

```
var imagesProp = {
  'padding': '3px',
  'backgroundColor': '#eded01',
  'borderSize': '1ps',
  'borderStyle': 'dashed',
  'borderColor': '#0001fe'
};

function highlightimages() {
  var allimages = document.getElementsByid('images');
//How do i start from here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var imagesProp = {
  'padding': '3px',
  'backgroundColor': '#eded01',
  'borderSize': '1ps',
  'borderStyle': 'dashed',
  'borderColor': '#0001fe'
};

function highlightImages() {
  //You do not use getElementsByid but getElementsByTagName 
  var allimages = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var nrallimgs = allimages.length;

  // traverses the <img> elements, and register onclick to each one
  // else, apply the properties defined in $imagesProp
  for(i=0; i<nrallimgs; i++) {
    allimages[i].onclick=function() {
   
      if(this.style.borderStyle == imagesProp.borderStyle) {
        this.style.padding = 'auto';
        this.style.background = 'none';
        this.style.border = 'none';
      }
      else {
        this.style.padding = imagesProp.padding;
        this.style.backgroundColor = imagesProp.backgroundColor;
        this.style.borderSize = imagesProp.borderSize;
        this.style.borderStyle = imagesProp.borderStyle;
        this.style.borderColor = imagesProp.borderColor;
      }
    }
  }
}

// calls the highlightImages() function to apply the effect
highlightImages();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class

```
  highlighted {
   padding: '3px';
   backgroundColor: '#eded01';
   borderSize: '1ps';
   borderStyle: 'dashed';
   borderColor: '#0001fe'
 }
```

**Using jQuery:**

```
var $element = $('#elementid');
$element.click(function () {
     $(this).toogleClass('highligted');
});
```